# location.pathname.indexOf Used to Target all Files in a Site Directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using location.pathname.indexOf to target the CSS on certain pages within the Volusion e-commerce framework. Basically, I'm limited to how I can edit certain CSS so I've found that if I use this Javascript, it provides me a way to edit on pages that I normally would not be able to.

For some of the products, they are generated dynamically and are all found within the folder "http://www.example.com/product-p/RANDOM_PRODUCT_NUMBER.htm" . I want every page within the "product-p" folder to be have it's CSS targeted. The problem is, I'm not sure exactly how to do that with location.pathname.indexOf, I've only ever used that to target one specific page directly.

I had read somewhere about using * (as is normal to target "all" files in a directory) but I'm not sure exactly how to use it within this Javascript. Here's an example of the code I've got so far (which is not working but works if I insert a specific page):

```
if (location.pathname.indexOf('/product-p/') != -1 ) {
$("#login_head").css('top','0px !important');
$("#login_head").css('left','0px !important');
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm lost, trying to figure out what you're trying to do. JS is a browser language that doesn't have access to file system. Can you provide an example html page and what should be the result of JS transforming it?

Comment: This code can actually add/edit the CSS on a page specific basis with jQuery/Javascript. It basically just generates CSS for the page in the parentheses. It works when you've got, for example, ('shoppingcart.asp') in the code but not if you have a directory. I believe there is a way to have that done though.